# Building C->Python library on 64-bit OS

Tags: python, visual-studio, 64-bit, swig, 32-bit

I have a third-party library that I have wrapped with Swig so that I can talk to it in Python. This is working for 32-bit OS/Python/third-party libs. Recently I received 64-bit versions of those libraries from the third party, so I want to rebuild the libraries to take advantage of this (using 64-bit Python and 64-bit OS, of course). However, I'm getting this error when I try to import the libraries:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "camera.py", line 1, in <module>
    import memhandler
  File "C:\neo\memhandler.py", line 26, in <module>
    _memhandler = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\neo\memhandler.py", line 22, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_memhandler', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

(memhandler is one of the SWIG libraries I'm building)
My searches have turned up other people who had this error due to 32-bit / 64-bit mismatches, so this would seem to indicate some kind of architecture mismatch, but I'm having trouble figuring out where it's going wrong.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008's command line to link against Python 2.7 64-bit; there's no version mismatch there (Python 2.7 64-bit was built with the same compiler, in other words). I've done this successfully in the past with a different program; sadly I can't tell by comparing this against it what's different about this one. I am using the 64-bit compiler (by running "vcvarsall.bat amd64" before starting).

Here's my Makefile:

```
PYROOT = C:\Python27x64
PYINCLUDE = /I$(PYROOT)\include /I$(PYROOT)\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include
PYLIBS = /LIBPATH:$(PYROOT)\libs python27.lib
ANDORLIBS = "Andor SDK3\atcorem.lib"
LIBS = $(PYLIBS) $(ANDORLIBS)

CXXFLAGS = /MD /EHsc /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /DNOPCH /O2 $(PYINCLUDE)

# We have two separate SWIG libraries to build here; one calls most of the
# Andor functions; the other does some intermediary work for us before
# calling certain special Andor functions. We also have to compile the
# intermediary library ourselves.
ANDOROBJS = neo_wrap.obj
WRAPOBJS = memhandler.obj
WRAPSWIGOBJS = memhandler_wrap.obj

ANDORTARGET = _neo.pyd
WRAPTARGET = _memhandler.pyd

all: $(ANDORTARGET) $(WRAPTARGET)

$(ANDORTARGET): $(ANDOROBJS)
    link /dll /DEBUG /NOLOGO /out:$@ /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS $(ANDOROBJS) $(LIBS)

$(WRAPTARGET): $(WRAPOBJS) $(WRAPSWIGOBJS)
    link /dll /DEBUG /NOLOGO /out:$@ /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS $(WRAPOBJS) $(LIBS)
    link /dll /DEBUG /NOLOGO /out:$@ /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS $(WRAPSWIGOBJS) $(LIBS) memhandler.obj

swig:
    C:\swigwin-2.0.4\swig.exe -c++ -python neo.i
    C:\swigwin-2.0.4\swig.exe -c++ -python memhandler.i

clean:
    del *ilk *lib *pdb *obj *exp *wrap.cxx *pyd *pyd.manifest
```

Any ideas? About the only thing I can think of is that I don't actually have 64-bit libraries; I don't know how to tell if a DLL/LIB file is 64-bit or 32-bit though.

Comment: dumpbin /headers will tell you if a DLL is 32-bit or 64-bit.

Comment: Okay, running dumpbin /headers for atcorem.lib gives this at the top: "8664 machine (x64)". So it looks like these are genuinely 64-bit. So much for that hypothesis.

Comment: Could it be that _memhandler.pyd depends on another DLL, e.g. from the Andor SDK, and you have a 32 bit version of that DLL in the PATH?

Comment: That was it! Fixed up my PATH in the batch file I was using to run the program and it works now. I seriously hadn't considered this as a possible problem because I had _thought_ that the 64-bit OS was clean; guess we mucked around with it a bit and left some old files sitting around. Many thanks!